# In Fight Club is Marla Singer a second figment of Jack's imagination?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, fight-club

After reading [this article on the existence of Marla Singer](http://blog.wekeroad.com/movies/marla-singer-didnt-exist), I am fairly convinced she represents his guilt and remorse. It seems entirely plausible Marla Singer materializes to remind Jack he is exploiting these therapy groups. In fact, even when Marla enters she says, "This is cancer, right?" nobody responds.

In addition to the blog, there are three examples of where I can think Marla Singer's presence is suggested but not required.

---

After Tyler's confrontation to Marla, he follows her to the laundromat where she removes the clothes from the dryer and proceeds next-door to sell them at a thrift shop. Even though the two are having a conversation in front of the thrift-shop attendant, she does not interject and instead only remains silent with a puzzled look on her face about the talk of bowel cancer.

Does this suggest that overly-civilized and feminized Jack invents Marla, a symbol of his guilt, and steers her toward outlet for his disdain of the order of society? Marla is self-destructive, manipulative, and a kleptomaniac. Whereas later on, Jack invents a hyper-masculine Tyler who is outwardly destructive, blatantly honest and disdains materialism and thus has no need to steal.

---

After Jack's boss finds some Fight Club paraphernalia on the Xerox machine, Jack says:

> I'd be very careful who I talked to about this.  It sounds like someone dangerous wrote it... someone who might snap at any moment, stalking from office to office with an Armalite AR-10 Carbine-gas semiautomatic, bitterly pumping round after round into colleagues and co-workers. Might be someone you've known for years... somebody very close to you. Or, maybe you shouldn't be bringing me every little piece of trash you pick up.

Then the phone rings, and it's Marla. Since we already know Jack invents Tyler as a way for him to cope with his repression from civilization, it seems like picking up the phone and talking to an imaginary person would use the same set of coping skills that led him to invent Tyler.

---

In the diner after not having seen Marla for an extended period of time, she orders food:

> "I'll have the clam chowder, the fried chicken with the baked potato with everything, and a chocolate chiffon pie."

If Marla isn't real, the waiter only responds to Jack's subsequent request for *Clean food, please.*, by saying,

> In that case, sir, may I advise against the lady eating the clam chowder?

We know the clam chowder at any of the restaurants is arguably the most contaminated food item. So, it would be logical for the waiter to recommend not eating clam chowder to anybody requesting clean food.

There are many possibilities as to why the waiter says the "**lady**" but it seems like this is the most damning to the theory of Marla's non-existence. The waiter may be attempting to allude to the fact that Jack isn't the same person as he is during Fight Club. But it may not be as bad as it seems at first glance, because the waiter doesn't use the pronoun **she** or **her**.

It is also acceptable to refer to a high-ranking woman to their face as "*the lady*".

Since Jack even thought to himself --

> Even if I could tell someone they had a good fight, I wouldn't be talking to the same man. Who you were in fight club is not who you were in the rest of the world.

Perhaps this is a play on Jack's lack of masculinity outside of Fight Club, the same way drill sergeants call their recruits ladies. After all, Jack does not want to be a celebrity, he wants to be one of the masses along with his followers.

---

Is there any more evidence or counter evidence to the claim?

Comment: Interesting theory +1.   I'll have a think about it - but the explanation for why the waiter says "lady" is quite weak.

Comment: Ahhhh I've been waiting for this one to crop up :3
INCOMING WALL-o-TEXT

Comment: The waiter is dressed up, therefore a more formal meaning than "her".

Comment: As an aside, becareful how much you're editing.  Too many edits in a short amount of time (think 1 edit every 10 min) will force this post as a CW

Comment: Sorry I erased my comment on accident, it was above TylerShads' second. It said the waiter may have been referring to Jack as `the lady` as in the highfalutin form of address to a high-ranking woman.

Comment: What does CW mean?

Comment: Community Wiki.  No rep gains and anyone can edit the post.

Comment: Maybe next time I'll edit the question in Word before posting it D:

Comment: There are actual Markdown editors out there with live previews.  I'm always for improving posts but feel if you're editing that much you should be careful if you want this post to gain some reputation :P.  10 recorded (in the history) self-edits trigger it and I think if there is 10 different people editing your post, it also flags it.

Comment: I never thought about this and I've probably watched this film more than any other. +1

Comment: Cayetano's mention of the line "Except for their humping, Tyler and Marla were never in the same room. My parents pulled this exact same act for years" is actually interesting since he states he never knew his dad as his father left before he ever knew him and started new family "franchises" all over the country... ok, not only does that make me wonder about the father not being there to be "pulling the same act for years" with his mother while "narrator" was a child, but also makes me wonder if Tyler setting up fight club "franchises" in every city is a model off of his father, or if his fath

Answer (score 58):

## Marla Singer is real.

And here is why.

Throughout the movie, she does have a certain ring about her that would allude her to the same appearance as Tyler. A mechanism to cope with him exploiting the groups by introducing a woman into the mix.  She is inherently, a real person in terms of the movie.

### The Restaurant.

Probably the most obvious reference to her reality is this scene where the waiter acknowledges both the existence of The Narrator (Jack from here on out) and Marla sitting together at the table

> In that case sir may I advise against the lady eating the clam chowder...

That article does reference a great counterpoint, stating that they know he is insane and compensate for it by making sure to continue Project Mayhem on their own even with a direct "Stop" order from him.  But I counter with a fact of **how does the waiter know this is another personality, let alone female in nature?**  The answer is, her physical existence.

### The Support Group

Her existence is acknowledged more than most people take into consideration.  If it was really Jack approaching the group after several meetings just asking

> This is cancer, right?

They would approach with more smiles and laughter on their face than surprise and disgust that a *woman* is joining their *male* support group.  Not to mention the fact that Bob would recognize "Cornelius" instantly.

Also, the other scene where they are embracing each other the proctor (leader?) of the group would have said something about Jack being alone hugging the air and hug him herself or some cheesy thing like that.  It is nigh on impossible that she would let him stand there alone (assuming Marla's non-existence) in a group that helps others cope with such strong emotions.

### The Thrift Store

Quick point here that if Marla is selling the clothes and she looks at *Jack* when Bowel Cancer is involved, why wouldn't she just look at Marla instead?

### The Ending

This is also the point that the article doesn't bring up in any great detail as it drives a train through this theory.

The simple premise of Project Mayhem members actively tracking down Marla and bringing her to Jack is shown as the ultimate proof of her existence.  It is one thing to allow your leader to have his little insane quirks of talking to himself, contradicting himself, even fighting himself.  But to bring his actual *alter ego* to him is quite impossible.  Let alone finding who she is if they have *seen her before and know her exact description*

Ladies and gentleman of the Jury, I submit with the aforementioned evidence, that Marla Singer is ***REAL***

---

An aside:

The book itself reveals a bit more to her existence than the movie does.

> Marla is a real person as it is because he sees her with a support group he decided to erase Tyler from existence in order to prevent him from ruining Marla's life further and then shoots himself when he thinks everything else is hopeless after the bomb fails.

The restaurant scene is also there but with more interaction between her and the waiter.

I applaud the movie in that it allows one to have this theory of Marla, vs her portrayal in the book where it is *much* more obvious that she is a real person.

Another aside that struck my mind reading that article is how the house is actually a physical representation of Jack's psyche.  I disagree in the physical part because then it can be argued that *anyone* that joined Fight Club and later PM is just *another*  alternate personality of his.  I do like thinking it is more of a symbolic representation, however, which fits a lot better.

Comment: Excellent refutation. However, one thing I'd like to point out is that there are some interpretations that at some point Jack actually becomes institutionalized, and the building at the end is an insane asylum. The Project Mayhem guys, along with Marla, who come into the room could actually be nurses and/or doctors.

Comment: The book implied the institutionalization doesn't happen until *after* shooting himself.  Presumably, one could assume the police searched the building, found him with a hole in his head, bombs around, etc and brought him in.  And/or PM members placed him in there in order to keep him out of jail and to 'get better' to lead them again (by exploiting the legal system, etc).

Comment: @TylerShads +1, agreed just after reading half of your answer. Will read it full later

Comment: While I agree with everything else you're saying, I don't think by her saying `This is cancer, right?` it is telling, because nobody really responds to her, and nobody notices except Jack. Although Bob may or may not, it's hard to tell. Her entrance may be the coalescence of an idea.

Comment: IIRC they all do stop their discussion and look over at her collectively.  Time to do some screenshot magic tonight methinks

Comment: @TylerShads You're right. I have come back to this question, and absolutely they do all look at her collectively. I am going to add another facet to this question; Why are there no scenes where Jack, Tyler and Marla are all in the same scene at the same time?

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves If you want to get *really* technical, any scene with Marla and *Jack* or Marla and Tyler, are really scenes with all 3.

Comment: @TylerShads True, but I was referring to the common literary theme when two people never appear in the same place at the same time are usually the same person. This happens when Mrs. Doubtfire and Daniel are never able to be in the same place at the same time, and he must rotate between tables at the final scene to be able to give the illusion that he is attending both dinners. Is there some parallel here, I wonder if Jack might have wondered this himself - if Tyler and Marla were the same person.

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves I think at that point it might warrant a whole other analysis question.

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's shown at the end where we get to know of Tyler not being real, that people knew the narrator was fighting himself, acting all weird. Scene: the first fight against "tyler" outside the bar, where the guys come out to see what's going on. So I think people knew about the weirdness.

Comment: The whole film is from the perspective of a man having an acute mental breakdown. The small details of people reacting can't be taken as reliable, notice the man touch Tyler's chest on the bus?

Answer (score 9):

I think I have proven Marla is not real, along with many other characters (including Bob). I made [a whole site for it](http://www.jackdurden.com) and will try to summarize some key points here, but I strongly advise you to visit the site for more details.

> **Marla and Tyler Dress the Same**
>
> One of the first clues that Marla is not real is her likeness to Tyler. [...] Tyler’s hair is styled and worn almost identical to Marla’s throughout most of the film. Marla and Tyler are both seen wearing a similar faux fur coat, wearing sunglasses, almost identical rings and they are seen smoking in virtually every scene in the film. Even the framing of the shots is nearly identical when they are shown wearing similar clothes as well as the same facial expressions.
>   [image]
>
> **Marla and Jack (Edward Norton) Dress the Same**
>
> This is even more telling than Marla’s likeness to Tyler, but slightly more symbolic. Jack (the narrator, Edward Norton) is seen gradually looking more like Marla up until the final scene where we see the silhouettes of the two standing together, holding hands. From the back, it is virtually impossible to tell who is who. Note how Jack’s long coat and lack of pants have made it seem as if he is wearing a dress, a near perfect mirror image of Marla as they watch the 12 skyscrapers be demolished.
>
> [image]
>
> **Marla Has No Reflection, Neither Does Tyler**
>
> Marla and Tyler do not have reflections, because they do not exist. Unless Jack is with Marla (or Tyler) their reflection or image will not appear. This is because this is the only time Marla is “real” to the narrator. We can see a great example of this in the scene when Tyler is saving Marla from suicide and goes to her hotel to save her. [...] When they both walk by, neither of them has a reflection. [...] The reason we see that Tyler and Marla have reflections in other scenes [...] is because at those points Jack was acting his himself observing the alter personality as a separate person. In the scene where Tyler goes to save Marla, Jack is supposedly not there, meaning Tyler and Marla are not actually being observed (except by us). We are being told to “imagine” what it would be like to see Tyler and Marla escape the hotel and in doing so the illusion of Marla and Tyler’s existence begins to disintegrate. We are not watching Tyler save Marla in this scene, we are watching Jack leave the hotel completely alone, yelling at the paramedics franticly about how Marla is infectious human waste (hence the user of the 3rd person when Marla is yelling at the paramedics.
>
> **Jack Becomes Marla In the Laundromat**
>
> In the laundromat scene we watch Marla take control over Jack, becoming his primary alternate personality. Marla opens 2 Speed Queen brand dryers and takes out multiple pairs of men’s blue jeans. She then walks to the vintage clothing store and sells them. [...] If Jack is Marla then this means he is selling his own pants to the thrift store and figuratively surrendering his masculinity. [...] Is there any other article of clothing that is more representative of Western “masculinity”? It is obviously a deliberate metaphor for Jack’s masculinity being hijacked by Marla, his alter-ego.
>
> Later in the film we see Marla wearing a pink bride’s maid dress she claims she “got at a thrift store.” What if Jack, acting as Marla, bought this dress at the same time he sold his own jeans? This would make perfect sense since Marla is seen selling her clothes at a vintage consignment store, which is for all intents and purposes the same exact thing as a thrift store. Marla is likely hinting at this when she says to Jack, “you can borrow it sometime,” since she knows it is actually Jack’s.
>
> At the end of the film we watch Jack run around frantically, without pants, after he has decided he wants Marla instead of Tyler and Project Mayhem. He has abandoned his masculinity entirely and is either accepting his emasculated self or is literally becoming a woman, depending on how you interpret the film. This culminates in the final scene where we see the mirror image of Marla and Jack holding hands. Jack creates Bob, then Marla, then Tyler, then finally betrays Bob and Tyler to accept his place as Marla (notice how Bob and Tyler both die the exact same way: a gun shot wound blowing out the back of their heads).
>
> **Marla Becomes Tyler On the Airplane**
>
> The first time we meet Tyler in the film is on the airplane. [...] On the plane Jack is talking to a middle aged black woman who is wearing sunglasses that resemble Tyler’s (see below comparison) and sitting next to Jack eating a meal. Jack then begins fantasizing about the plane breaking apart mid-flight after it collides with another plane. After he snaps out of this fantasy, Tyler is now sitting in place of the woman. How on Earth could this be possible..? (“It’s called a changeover. The movie goes on, and nobody in the audience has any idea.” - Jack)
>
> This means the woman does not exist and Jack is likely sitting alone, either talking to himself or imagining himself talking to the woman and to Tyler. We watched a woman turn into Tyler, sitting right next to Jack. [...] Furthermore, we see the woman is somewhat older and eating from a tray, which is an interesting parallel to how Marla provides food for herself: stealing Meals on Wheels trays of food. This scene denotes the transition from Marla being the prominent alternate personality of Jack, to Tyler taking over.
>
> Jack boarded the plane as Marla, the destruction sequence is showing us the “end” of Marla and then he “becomes” Tyler. This explains why he loses his baggage once he gets off the plane and is so confused as to why it was vibrating. Jack didn’t pack his bag, Marla did! He is now Tyler, and this is why the damaged cardboard box is the only luggage left on the conveyor belt, since this is Tyler’s luggage.
>
> [image]
>   Fincher could not have made this much clearer when you consider the emergency exit sign above the door [...] You can tell the female turns into a man by the change of clothing and hair between the first and final image of the emergency exit diagram.
>
> **Testicles and Balls, Marla is Jack Post-Testicular Cancer**
>
> One of the weirdest aspects of Fight Club is the fixation on testicles. If you look at the film as a commentary on the emasculation of men in Western culture, it makes sense. But it goes deeper and helps explain why Marla and other characters are not real. There is an over-arching theme of “removing” manhood throughout the film. Whether literally removing someone’s testicles or through references to sex toys. In either case it suggests the removal of what defines a man.
>
> If Jack is Marla then it makes sense that Bob and Marla are both members of the testicular cancer group. Jack feels emasculated, at first he only feels moderately insecure, so he imagines Bob there to help cope with his insecurity and anxiety about his actual testicular cancer. He then creates Marla, who helps him cope but also represents his feeling of being literally feminized by the prospect of losing his balls. If most of these things are not happening at all or are happening differently than they are presented (i.e. interactions with Marla, the support groups, etc.) then this evidence lends itself to the theory that we are simply seeing Jack’s insecurities leak into the narrative through the coping mechanisms he created to suppress them.
>
> **Dildos, Dildos Everywhere**
>
> Dildos are extremely prominent throughout the film and lend a lot of credibility to the fact that Marla is not real. Dildos represent the fact that Marla is taking Jack’s masculinity or that he is surrendering it, and this could likely be a metaphorical device used to illustrate Jack literally no longer physically has his testicles.
>
> Another significant place we see a dildo is on Marla’s dresser, which is a very interesting place for it. When Tyler goes to save Marla, he leans against the dresser, causing the dildo to move. Marla then says, “Oh don’t worry, it’s not a threat to you.” This could be interpreted a number of ways. If Marla is Jack, and Jack is Tyler, then the dildo is likely not going to be used by any of them, so it is literally not a threat. In addition, if Tyler is a coping mechanism who represents masculinity, he presumably actually has a penis – so the dildo is not a threat – while Jack who has been possibly physically emasculated would see the dildo as a threat.
>
> In addition, the positioning of the dildo on the dresser and next to the door lends itself to another interpretation that I feel makes more sense. If Jack believes that this is where Marla stays, yet he is Marla, then this is a clever way of communicating to the viewer that Jack is leaving his manhood at the door when he arrives and takes on the role of Marla. This would also help add even more strength to my vibrating suitcase theory (below).
>
> **The Vibrating Suitcase (Dildos Part II)**
>
> This is one of the strongest points for Marla’s non-existence. The most interesting part about this scene is that Jack is utterly confused. If he had been the person to actually pack his bags, then surely he would understand what COULD be vibrating in the suitcase. The security guard even says, “9 times out of 10 it’s an electric razor.” But Jack continues to look at the security guard confused and says, “my suitcase was vibrating?” Implying he has no idea what could possibly be the cause.
>
> However, if Jack is actually Marla, then Marla is likely the one who packed his bags. Which means there actually is a dildo in the luggage. Jack acts totally confused about this because he himself has no idea he is Marla. [...] The security guard even hints at this by saying, “of course it’s company policy never to imply ownership in the event of a dildo, we have to use the indefinite article a dildo, never your dildo” and looks at Jack skeptically. [...] This is brilliant because the security guard is essentially saying we cannot say it’s actually Jack’s dildo, because we do not know he is Marla, it is indefinite and ambiguous on purpose.
>
> **Marla and Jack Live In a Hotel, the Paper Street House Doesn’t Exist**
>
> The house Tyler lives in, where Jack moves into and Project Mayhem uses as a base does not exist. Equally interesting is Marla does not have an apartment…or a house…she lives in a hotel. [...] Who else do we know that spends almost all of his time in hotels? Oh right, Jack. When Marla calls Jack to tell him she is committing suicide, Jack says, “just picturing Marla throw herself around her crummy apartment” but we know that Marla is staying at a hotel because the exterior shots of her “apartment” have a neon sign in the background that says “Rooms”.
>
> In the beginning after meeting with Tyler after his condo explodes, Jack says “ah, I need to find a hotel.” After Jack’s condo exploded, he met with Tyler, said he needed a hotel, and actually went and got one. He did not go to the Paper Street house, because it does not exist. This explains why when he handed the beer to Tyler, the neon sign in the background went out (which is a visual representation of his masculinity…it’s an actual penis). He was transitioning back into Marla and turning off his masculine persona. Tyler and Marla’s residences are the exact “same” residence, in that it is only the hotel Jack is living at but he is imagining two separate places for his two separate alternate personalities. He has multiple people living in one “house” which also serves as a clever metaphor for his psyche.
>
> This helps explain Jack’s distaste when Marla begins spending more time at the Paper Street house, why Tyler and Marla cannot be in the same “room” together (because he cannot be two people simultanousely) and why Project Mayhem causes the Paper Street house to turn into a “living, breathing thing”. Jack says, “She invaded my support groups now she invaded my home” and explains why Tyler is adamant about not being in the same room. The personalities are losing their compartmentalization (think about it, Marla begins living at the Paper Street house even, then Bob moves in and Project Mayhem, they all wind up in one house or one “compartment”) and Jack is losing his sanity as a result, which we watch deteriorate through the rest of the film.
>
> **Tyler Saves Marla from Committing Suicide**
>
> Even Jack says “now why would Tyler think it’s a good idea to save Marla?” This is partly a sly reference to the twist ending, where we discover Tyler is Jack. But if you take this deeper you realize it’s because if Marla dies, Jack dies, meaning Tyler also dies. If Marla is committing suicide and she is also Jack, then it means Jack will die as well as Tyler. In other words, we are watching Jack lying in the bed trying to commit suicide – “calling” Tyler at the non-existent Paper Street House. This is the incentive for Tyler to save her. If Jack dies, everyone dies.
>
> **Left In the Copier**
>
> Jack’s boss finds the fight club rules in the copier and confronts Jack about them. Jack replies with something Tyler might say, then says “Tyler’s words coming out of my mouth. And I used to be such a nice guy.” Immediately following the phone rings and it is Marla saying she thinks she has breast cancer. [...] Is it really a coincidence that Marla calls him right after we see Jack being taken over by Tyler’s personality (i.e. the words he chooses to use to tell his boss off?) This is Marla saying to him that she is basically dying and her personality isn’t needed anymore, she’s trying to get his attention so she can continue to exist to Jack. [...] Jack has just been found out along with his association with Fight Club, an enormously panic-inducing experience, triggering the need for his coping mechanism, Marla, to help him through the ordeal. Right on cue, the phone rings and it is Marla to help get him out of the situation, literally asking him to leave work immediately and come to her house to check her for breast cancer.
>
> **Self Improvement is Masturbation**
>
> This is a big one. There are a ton of references to masturbation and “fucking yourself” throughout the film. The most notable scene is where Tyler and Jack board the bus and Tyler says, “Self improvement is masturbation, now self destruction…” and trails off. [...] Fast forward to when Tyler saves Marla and they are now in the habit of constantly having sex with each other. If masturbation is self improvement, and if Marla, Tyler and Jack are all the same person, then Jack is masturbating. In the scenes where Tyler and Marla are having sex and yelling, what is Jack doing? He is engaging in self improvement. He is shown reading and exercising while the house is literally being destroyed and falling on his head.
>
> **Infectious Human Waste**
>
> Everyone remembers how Tyler Durden makes his soap – stolen fat from the liposuction clinic. In the scene where they go to steal the fat they alert the attention of the security guard (more on this later) and hide behind a dumpster marked “infectious waste”. To be more specific, the contents of the dumpsters are in fact infectious human waste. When Tyler had gone to save Marla, we see her yelling at the paramedics and emergency responders that are coming to save her that she’s “infectious human waste.” Even more interestingly she is speaking about herself in the 3rd person. This makes perfect sense since Marla is Tyler and in this scene we are actually watching Jack running away from the hotel and speaking about Marla. [...] What are the odds that Marla, if she were her own individual person and not a figment of Jack’s imagination, would choose to use the word’s “She’s infectious human waste!” to describe herself in the third person when we know that Jack and Tyler literally use infectious human waste to make soap. This is a deliberate connection the director was trying to make.
>
> **“I Want to Have Your Abortion”**
>
> After Tyler and Marla have sex Marla famously says “I haven’t been fucked like that since grade school.” This line in the film was actually improvised by Helena. The actual line in the script is “I want to have your abortion.” This is an odd choice of words even for someone who is supposed to play a dark and cynical character like Helena – it kind of doesn’t make sense. However if you consider that Marla is Tyler and Jack, then Jack is fucking himself, and will ultimately destroy himself – essentially an abortion of himself. This makes her choice of words make much more sense. “Self improvement is masturbation, now self destruction…” is related to this also. [...] Marla is Jack, Jack is also Tyler, when Marla and Tyler are done having sex she says “I want to have your abortion” which is the same as self destruction, since they are the same person.

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). In contrast to providing a link-only answer you might want to sumamrize the key points of your theory in the actual answer.

Comment: I think your observations on that site are excellent, but the comments are kind of all over the place. I wonder what you think of the fact that there's never the three in the same room at the same time, or that Tyler never says anything to Marla.

Comment: I tried to summarize the linked website a bit. It might still be a bit much (well, the site is really informative and there's few to strip) and it would actually have been better for the OP to summarize it a bit in his own words (which I did neither feel confident nor compelled enough for), but at least now I think it makes for an actual (and upvotable) answer.

Comment: When it's already granted that Jack has constructed an alternate persona, **any** element is *easily* explained by compartmentalization/delusion/etc.  but cinematic 'explanatory power' is no more challenging or profound than any degree of [solipsism syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism_syndrome).  A far tighter and more-fun 'extra twist' is [here](https://whatwouldbaledo.com/2012/08/25/i-am-jacks-fight-club-fan-theory/#more-822): Tyler is real.

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves, never having all 3 person[alitie]s in the room at once is already explained if Marla is a discrete human; believing she's another figment doesn't require any extra argument if we already accept that Tyler is a figment.

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard of this theory before but it does make sense from the movie perspective only though the book does make it clearer that she exists. Just to play Devil's Advocate to TylerShads I'm going to say that Marla is another one of Tyler Durden's personalities.

Let's take it from the top.

She walks into a testicular cancer group smoking and asks "This is cancer right?" Everyone stares at her.

She shows up at all of the groups smoking and no one says anything to her about it.

She invades the penguin dream.

She finds him when he thought he was done with ever having seen her again. "You stopped coming to group."

Tyler rescues her from her suicide attempt, shes yells things to the emergency crew which they ignore.

Ed Norton sees Project Mayhem grab her on a bus that he just put her on when it seems highly unlikely that so many members would have been on the bus or any for that matter.

### We see her again at the end brought to him by Project Mayhem.

Okay so we have Marla Singer this mysterious woman who seems to be on a very similar path to Tyler Durden or whoever he was before this movie begins. She has troubles and gets through them by pretending to need group therapy for her own cathartic reasons. She first appears when he has finally gotten some release from his insomnia by lying at therapy groups. She stops this release by merely existing. She is a reflection of his lies. Pretty and obnoxious. She is very much like Tyler Durden (Brad Pitt) yet she dwells on misery and isn't as honest. It is telling that she appears when he summons his spirit animal.

But why would she be addressed as a Lady by the waiter and why did the testicular group stare at her. I think the answer is quite simple. We see that Tyler Durden sometimes dresses as Ed Norton and sometimes more like his ideal self Brad Pitt I think he also dresses as Marla Singer if she is indeed him. I think it's shown by one of my previous [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/when-grabbing-the-commisoner-what-is-tyler-durden-actually-doing) that Tyler Durden sometimes sees himself in more places then one at the same time since he has split his personalty into doing two different actions sometimes. In the goup seen he's being hugged by Bob but then Marla walks in. I think the reaction is one he received when he had walked in as "Marla" before. After all man in drag could have as much reason to be in a group as any other man but a woman might very well be asked to leave. I think his groups are used to him switching between Marla and whatever other name he chooses. Project Mayhem would likewise be used to Tyler Durden switching and would address him as Lady if they saw him dressed as one. They are his soldiers and conform to his rules which are pretty much destroy all the rules. Also Marla is constantly trying to make Tyler aware of who Tyler Durden is. Her interaction with everyone else is on the same level as Tyler (Brad) and even Tyler (Ed) when he is watching Tyler(Brad) interact with others.

One more thing Marla never talks about a job yet she has an apartment. She is always reachable by Tyler and she eats by stealing meals on wheels. My guess is that Tyler was helping the elderly as one of his part-time jobs. Those that would be close to death. When one of them died and no one noticed then Marla got an apartment which is probably paid for by a SS Check still coming.

Comment: First of all, I like both theories and their respective answers (and am not sure which one is true, but maybe this isn't the point anyway). In addition to that, the fact that *Marla* doesn't call him *"Tyler"* before he is already on the right track of discovering the truth might on the one hand be seen as a simple narrative coincidence, but might on the other hand fit to the theory of her being not real, since it is not before he himself gets the idea of being *Tyler* that "she" does even call him so and this might just be part of his mental discovery process.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure because I didn't read the book. But in the movie, when Marla crosses the street to the thrift shop a car stops to avoid hitting Marla. From the perspective of the camera there was absolutely no reason for the car to emergency brake to a stop. However, if Marla were a manifestation of Jack's psyche, the perspective would be Marla looking back at Jack and Jack (Marla) would be looking, in essence, at himself. Sorry to confuse the issue but  both sides seem completely plausible.

My thought is that Marla is a manifestation of Jack's feminine side and he does actually cross dress because Marla talks about her bridesmaid dress and tells Jack "you can borrow it sometime". Also the first time we see Jack smoking is at work which illustrates to me that Marla would be Jack's daytime character and Tyler would be Jack's night character crossing paths occasionally morning and evening which would be a result of his insomnia.

Comment: Wow, I've always thought the line "You can borrow it sometime" was odd, but I think you are on to something here.

Answer (score 2):

The scene in which Marla is asking whom Jack is speaking to while Tyler is in the basement is interesting. Why would she ask if she was also another split personality? Tyler manages to avoid being in the same room with her throughout the movie. Why? Also, why else would Tyler demand Jack to never talk about Tyler or what goes on in the house to Marla. One would assume, that Tyler viewed her as a threat, therefore as a real person.

Also, Marla had paramedics outside her door. A split personality that manages to actually get a suicide response team outside their door, then jet off with another spilt personality, has to be a record as spilt personalities go.

These are just a few things I noticed while watching it last. Open to critique.

Comment: Jack even says "Except for their humping, Tyler and Marla were never in the same room. My parents pulled this exact same act for years." There is a really common literary theme where one person is pretending to be two people, and cannot ever be in the same room with that other person, think of Mrs. Doubtfire at the restaurant scene. He is supposed to be there at two tables, being two people, but has to keep running away and making excuses why he can't be in the same place at the same time.

Comment: As for the basement comment, is it not possible that since Tyler and Marla are two of Jack's personality fragments that they can't stand to acknowledge each other's existence?

Answer (score 2):

My comment is about the book not the movie, but it is relevant to this thread because many of you think that Marla's ontological claims are stronger on page than on screen. I beg to disagree.  But then my theory is even more extreme than any I see here. I think that all of Project Mayhem is a part of "Jack's" delusion. None of it is real. If I am right about this, it would answer the objection about the waiter (which I admit is a strong argument for Marla's existence *if Project Mayhem is real*). My evidence for believing that PM is an illusion? The mechanic scene (where the mechanic drives the car and swerves into incoming traffic). In the movie, the mechanic is played by Brad Pitt (a strong hint that the mechanic is not real). Things are much less clear in the book, where the mechanic is presented as a separate character. If the mechanic is indeed Tyler, we are asked to believe that three Space Monkeys would sit obediently in the back of the car (barking "Sir!") while a single lunatic has a conversation with himself and drives toward oncoming traffic. Even the most dedicated follower would be moved to interject, "Excuse me, Mr Durden, sir, but . . ." in these circumstances. But the problem vanishes if there is only one real person in the car.

Comment: The point Tyler was making to the narrator in the car, was also being made to the space monkeys. They were being led by example, since all they saw was Tyler.

Answer (score 0):

There's a sequel to Fight Club in the form of a graphic novel made by the same guy who wrote the original book, Chuck Palahnuik. Since it never comes up in either books, it's safe to assume she's real.

Answer (score -2):

My reason on why the waiter called him "Lady" is because they're used to him acting like a woman so they can tell the difference between Tyler and Marla. So as a sign of respect, they play along with it.

Comment: The problem here is, in the same sentence he is talking to who he believes is Tyler (calling him sir) and talking about Marla (the lady). The only way this would work is if he'd be jumping around the chairs, or at the very least talking about the invisible lady and making requests in her name. They only stopped Marla from eating tainted food, after Tyler's direct request, so, again, this leads to the belief she is a different person. Unless you think the waiter would serve tainted clam chowder to a "drag Tyler" on purpose.